# How can I get a file list, recursively?

Tags: bash, shell

I would like to have output with the following format:

```
/media/username/New/Audio/ｔｉｍｅ ｍａｃｈｉｎｅ by Ariya Hedie.mp3
/media/username/New/Audio/You areever alone by Dj Quads.flac
/media/username/New/Audio/You'rehe Boss by The Barr Brothers.opus
/media/username/New/Audio/Your Wedding byosimo Fogg.mp3
/media/username/New/Audio/You,y Love by Floppyircus.opus
/media/username/New/Library/Yup byteven O'Brien.flac
/media/username/New/Library/Zen by Warptech.opus
/media/username/New/Library/無機質な怒りに対する優しさの反論.opus
/media/username/New/Library/鎖 -hain Border byaoyaakamata.opus
```

The files are music files with different formats, opus, mp3 and others, the folders do not contain non music files. The file names often have Unicode characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean you want the full paths of the regular files whose name ends in `.lua` in or under the `/media/username` directory, then you could use the standard `find`.

```
LC_ALL=C find /media/username -name '*.lua' -type f
```

If you wanted that list sorted lexically, you could pipe it to `sort`, but that would only work in the special case where none of the file paths contain newline characters and that could end up scattering the lines of a multi-line file path. For instance with:

```
/media/username/my
dir/my
strange file.lua
```

Once piped to `sort`, that becomes (in most locales):

```
dir/my
/media/username/my
strange file.lua
```

To sort those paths without breaking multi-line paths, you can do:

```
LC_ALL=C find /media/username -name '*.lua' -type f -print0 |
  sort -z |
  tr '\0' '\n'
```

Though that requires GNU extensions of `find` and `sort` and therefore is no longer standard.

Alternatively, you can use the zsh shell instead of bash. Its globs are sorted lexically by default like in all shells but also allow filtering by file type (with the `.` qualifier as the equivalent of `-type f` for instance here) and support recursive globbing:

```
print -rC1 /media/username/**/*.lua(ND.)
```

---

Some other alternatives to `find` are [`rawhide`](https://github.com/raforg/rawhide) with a C-like query language:

```
LC_ALL=C rh -e '"*.lua" && file' /media/username
```

Or [`fd-find`](https://github.com/sharkdp/fd), sometimes available as `fdfind` on some systems:

```
fdfind -usgtf '*.lua' /media/username
```

Short for:

```
fdfind --unrestricted --case-sensitive --glob --type file '*.lua' /media/username
```

(`fdfind` also has a `-e`/`--extension` but it doesn't seem to honour the `-s`/`--case-sensitive` flag¹ and I find it generally has that annoying tendency of thinking it knows better than you what you want).

Neither `fdfind` nor `rh` have built-in support to sort the list, but you can use the same trick of getting them to print the list NUL-delimited (both with the `-0` option), pipe to `sort -z` and then convert the NULs to newlines with `tr` if you want a sorted list.

The `*.lua` pattern is the same kind of pattern as used in shell globs. `*` matches any number of characters. To match any sequence of bytes whether they make up characters or not, with some tools and on some systems or versions there of, we set the locale the  `C` by passing `LC_ALL=C` to the environment of the finding command.

If you want to find any regular file regardless of their name, you can

- remove the `-name '*.lua'` with `find` (and you no longer need the `LC_ALL=C`)
- change `**/*.lua` to `**/*` in zsh,
- change `"*.lua" && file` to just `file` (or even `f`) in `rh` (and again no need for `LC_ALL=C`.
- change `'*.lua'` to `'*'` with `fdfind` or remove the `-g`/`--glob` option and use a `.` regex as the pattern.

To match on files whose name ends only in one of `.mp3`, `.flac`, `.opus`:

- `'(' -name '*.flac' -o -name '*.mp3' -o -name '*.opus' ')' -type f` in standard `find` (some `find` implementations also support `-regex` but the regex flavour and syntax varies between implementations).
- `**/*.(flac|opus|mp3)` in zsh
- `"*.@(flac|opus|mp3)" && file` in rh (on systems where `fnmatch()` supports ksh88 extended glob pattern operators), or use `"\.(flac|opus|mp3)\z".re && file` if not.
- `-ustf '\.(flac|open|mp3)$'` in fdfind (using regex instead of glob patterns).

To match case insensitively,

- `'(' -name '*.[fF][lL][aA][cC]' -o -name '*.[mM][pP]3' -o -name '*.[oO][pP][uU][sS]' ')' -type f` in standard `find` (some `find` implementations also support `-iname` and `-iregex` for that).
- `**/*.(#i)(flac|opus|mp3)` in zsh (needs `set -o extendedglob` beforehand)
- `"*.@(flac|opus|mp3)".i && file` in rh (on systems where `fnmatch()` supports ksh88 extended glob pattern operators), or use `"\.(flac|opus|mp3)\z".rei && file` if not.
- Remove `-s`/`--case-sensitive` in fdfind. You'll also need `-i`/`--ignore-case` if the pattern contains uppercase letters.

---

If you want to get that list of files in an array so you can do anything with them, with zsh, it's just a matter of:

```
set -o extendedglob
files=( /media/username/**/*.(#i)(flac|opus|mp3) )
do-anything-with $files
```

In `bash`:

```
readarray -td '' < <(find ... -print0 | sort -z)
do-anything-with "${files[@]}"
```

(needs bash 4.4 or newer).

---

<sup>¹ Its `-e` also seems to fail to match on file names which have something that cannot be decoded in UTF-8 just to the left of the extension (even in locales that don't use UTF-8). It does however consider that for a file called just `.lua`, `lua` is not the extension, which may actually be desirable. To achieve that effect with approaches based on glob patterns, you can change the pattern to `*?.lua` or `?*.lua` to make sure there's at least one character (one byte with `LC_ALL=C`) before the extension.</sup>

Comment: The files are music files with different formats, opus, mp3 and others, the folders do not contain non music files. The file names often have rare Unicode characters. Alphabetically sorted, which I wanted to ask in a separate question in case I cannot find out how it works.

Comment: Your question shows a list of lua files, not music files.

Comment: I edited it now to containing music files.

Answer (score 1):

With `globstar` and `extglob` enabled, you can recursively find filenames that match a certain pattern.

```bash
shopt -s globstar extglob
```

For example, to print all files under `media/` that end with either `mp3`, `flac` or `opus`, you can run:

```bash
printf '%s\n' media/**/*.@(mp3|flac|opus)
```

If you need to process each matching file, you can do it without invoking an external program like `find`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s globstar extglob

for file in media/**/*.@(mp3|flac|opus); do
    echo "do something with $file"
done
```

In addition, you can add the `nullglob` option to ensure that no output is generated if there are no matches.

---

You could do the same thing with the `find` command, but it is much harder to write, and therefore more error-prone:

```bash
find media/ \( \( -name '*.mp3' \) -o \( -name '*.flac' \) -o \( -name '*.opus' \) \) -exec echo do something with '{}' \;
```